# Decrease the Word Error Rate while training a model for automatic speech recognition

Tags: deep-learning, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, loss

I am training a speech to text model. On the very first epoch, the WER is 0.33, for 2nd epoch WER is still the same, however training loss has increased while the validation loss has decreased.

Apart from lowering the learning rate, what else can be done to make the model learn, atleast overfit?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the amount of training data, thats the only major factor. All those learning rate things and hyperparameters are tiny compared to the proper architecture and huge database.

Comment: Ok. I am using deepspeech2, so the architecture should be good enough. Increasing the data is something I plan to do next. But why is the model not overfitting? Why did the train loss increase (by about 20%)?

Comment: Deepspeech is very old and not really good architecture, wav2letter convolution one is much better. As for not overfitting, with small dataset models converge to local minimum, they might not converge properly at all. You can start reasonable end-to-end learning from 500 hours of data or so.